# Why is there space between the element and its border?

Tags: css, svg, flexbox, border, css-grid

Happens when mixing `svg`s with flexbox or grid.

See this simplified example:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  flex: initial;
}

svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Ala ma kota. A kot ma Alę</span>
  <svg>
    <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="red"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The problem happens very inconsistently (seems to depend on the surrounding box size, which in turn depends on the screen size & zoom - at least this is my hypothesis), so in case it is not visible to you let me show you a screenshot of what I see here:

[image]

See this spurious white space between the red image and its border? Its the rightmost border.

For my use case, this space does not only look ugly but is almost unacceptable: I'm trying to implement a health bar in a game and this space hints that the bar is not full even if it is.

Why does this space happen and is there any way to get rid of it?

(Firefox, if this matters.)

Comment: sub pixel rendring .. not difficult to get rid of

Comment: nothing on Chrome by the way

Comment: I'm using firefox to run your snippet but there is no white space at all. What firebox version are you using? Can you try to update your firefox.

Comment: @ChickenSoups 69.0, which is the latest one. Try resizing your screen or zooming in & out, the issue seems to appear and disappear randomly when I do this

Answer (score 0):

I tried to resizing on firefox but no luck to reproduce the white space. When zoom in & out I saw it happen event on chrome. When I inspect element there are some weird pixel float number (eg: 10.234px). Pixel is the smallest unit in normal screen, so the normal screen can show up the weird result above. In some retina device, it might work well.

P/S: there is one tricky way to get rid of it, when your character at full health, you set the background color of svg tag to "red", I had tried this way and see the white space go away.